# About the long comment list

Tags: feature-request, comments

[Here an other post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4490/how-should-we-handle-how-to-find-a-reference-requests?cb=1) with a huge amount of comments below each post. I'm feeling annoyed by this: or I have to clic to let them appear if I want to read them all, or I have to scroll a lot for nothing if I do not care about the comments. Is there a way to overcome this issue ?

I propose some ways to resolve the problem:

- allow some posts (especially in the meta part) to be more forum-like (no comment allowed for instance). That could be something like the *Wiki community* option.
- add a small floating on the bottom of the page link going to the next answer (for those who knows Gmail, a link like *go to the next discussion message* on Gmail)
- add a link to expand / discard *all* the comment of a given page (close to  the *comment, edit, share* buttons)

Or eventually all of these options ! Please tell me what you think about that.

Comment: To me, "forum like" means more comments, really. In a forum there's only one post and everything else is a comment. Here, there's a question and answers (important distinction being that questions must be real questions and answers must be real answers; not comments), with less emphasis on commenting,

Comment: @Manishearth To be honest, I add this *forum-like* option because I've tried to be exhaustive, but that's definitely not something I really want. I would vote for the *next answer* button, and an *expand / collapse all comments* button. They sound easier to implement, and could be a nice feature for the site. Thanks for your comment and your answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, Metas have their heart buried in comments. That's why the system doesn't disturb you often to *go to chat* while commenting in meta. Second, our meta is barely flooded. I suggest you to go to [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Have a look at some upvoted question, it will be flooded with comments. Moderation over there is very difficult due to their over-population. I don't say that we don't need it. But, mods will definitely take some action if they see obsolete/offensive comments.

In this case, it's just a discussion. So, we can keep it as it is. It isn't that much annoying...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was asking for the main site, but that's true the example I gave is characteristic of the meta, which is not a big issue I believe.

Comment: It does tell to go to chat actually ...

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the main site, there shouldn't be long comment discussions in the first place. If you see this happening, just flag it and ask the participants to move the discussion to chat.

In case of the meta site, a "hide comments" feature would be useful (also the "next post --I like that idea" , but IMO on meta comments are something that need reading too, sometimes they contain vauable points. Sometimes.

FWIW I think that the amount of comments by default shown on that meta post is ridiculous, usually only 5 or so get shown and the rest are hidden. Maybe it's because the comments are longer than usual that I'm noticing this , but usually the bulk of the comments are well hidden.

Comment: So, let's try to add a "next post" button ?

Comment: @Oaoa This meta post should be enough to get a reply. Alternatively, propose it on [metase] but you shouldn't have to.